# how to call solidity fallback function from react front end client app

Tags: reactjs, solidity

In my solidity smart contract there is a fallback function as follow:

```
contract MyContract {
//rest of contract
...

//**Fallback function**
    function () payable external {}
}
```

In my react client app , i have following code snippet:

```
... 
const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        MyContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );
...
await instance.methods.send({from:this.state.accounts[0],value:this.state.chargeValue})
...
```

in the console log following error
TypeError: this.state.contract.methods.send is not a function

in the contract javascript test script i can call fallback function with following code:

```
const MyContractInstance = await MyContract.deployed();
    
await MyContractInstance .sendTransaction({value:"1000000000000000000" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating the `Contract` instance and using its helper methods (there is no helper method to execute the fallback function), you can build a tx with missing `data` field.

```
await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    to: deployedNetwork.address,
    from: this.state.accounts[0],
    value: this.state.chargeValue
});
```

If you don't specify the `data` field, it's going to be empty, which results in executing the contract fallback function.

Docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction

Comment: Many thanks for your answer , just one more thing , how can I call fallback function from solidity test script. I could call it from  javascript test script but I don't know how to call it from solidity test script.

Comment: @MohammadMomtaz In Solidity test, you can use the low-level `.call()` member of `address` type. Example: `externalContractAddress.call("")` (the empty string is the empty data field) ...  Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/types.html#members-of-addresses